# How to define a singleton javascript class in a typescript declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following code is in my "test-file.js" file, I want to port it into a "test-file.d.ts" file so that i can then import it into my "test1.ts" and code against the JavaScript "Types" in Typescript.

I haven't been able to figure out how in my "test-file.d.ts" to define the below in such a way that the same implementation exists from Typescript.

```
(function(application) {

application.Message = function() {

    this.m_messageContents = "New Message";

};

application.Message.prototype.getApplicationMessageContents = function() {
    return this.m_messageContents;
};

application.SystemFactory = (function(){

var factory =
    /**
     * @lends application.SystemFactory
     */
    {
        createMessage: function() {
            return application.Message();
        }
    };
    return factory;

}());

}(application));
```

I do not want to re-code this file into a *.ts file, instead as stated above i want to import it into my "test1.ts".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if this is ok to you:

```
declare module application {
    export class Message {
        getApplicationMessageContents(): string;
    }

    export class SystemFactory {
        static createMessage(): Message;
    }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
let message = application.SystemFactory.createMessage();
let content = message.getApplicationMessageContents();
```

As you can see, you will declare the `static createMessage(): Message;`as static and not the class.

Comment: That is close, however it needs to be like this...                                         let message = application.SystemFactory.createMessage(); and              let content = message.getApplicationMessageContents(); The code would need to look something like this... (this obviously doesn't work though) declare module application {
    export class Message {
        getApplicationMessageContents(): string;        
    }
    
    export static class SystemFactory {
        createMessage(): Message;
    }
}

Comment: Thank you, Diullei.